# Get a dynamic type object in an Asp.net View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to create a Logging system for an ASP.Net MVC 6 application, that links the log message to certain objects.

For example:

- User {0} purchased {1}
- Item {0} was restocked with provider {1}, purchase placed by (2)

Which would map to:

- User John Apple purchased Box
- Item Clock was restocked with provider Casio, purchase placed by Johnny

**What I have so far is a "Log" method that receives an IEnumerable, and an IEnumerable ids**

For example:

- EnumObjectType.User:2
- EnumObjectType.Product:1
- ...

I already have all the code to to save in the database this arrays, reading them, converting them to enums, etc. However, I don't know how to make the "View" part of the application.

Namely, convert a Log.Message (an instance), for example: 
`User {0} purchased {1}` to `User <a href="#">John Apple</a> purchased <a href="#">Box</a>`

**What do I need?**

From the "Log Model View" how can I get the "name" property of ANY model (query for a given object, and use its property) knowing its type (the EnumObjectType), and its ID?

**Additional details**

All 'models' that can be logged will implement an interface that contains two methods, a ToLinkStructure that returns the link to a given instance of that class (e.g. /User/Details/{0}) and a ToLoggableString that returns a string that quickly represents an instance (E.g. "User: " + this.username)

Thanks!
I tried to give all details that could cross my mind, but if there's something missing I'll be glad to add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to read a property of an object with a type you don't know until runtime. That can be done like this:

```
var value = myObject.GetType().GetProperty("name").GetValue(myObject, null);
```

A better option would be, as you are saying your classes implement an interface, is to put that property in the interface, and accept only instances implementing this interface in your logging function.

```
public interface MyInterface{
    string Name { get; }
}
```